# Dynamic Pivot N row to N column

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot, dynamic-pivot

I want to convert a number of rows into columns
I found the following code

My question is, can I stored procedure output in a table?

from this link
https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:::::P11_QUESTION_ID:4471013000346257238

the code

```
create table fish (

fish_id number,

fish_type varchar2(3),

fish_weight number);

insert into fish values (1,'COD',20);

insert into fish values(1,'HAD',30);

insert into fish values(2,'COD',45);

insert into fish values(2,'HKE',10);

insert into fish values(2,'LIN',55);

insert into fish values(3,'CTY',90);

insert into fish values (3,'HAD',60);

insert into fish values (3,'COD',52);
```

/

```
create or replace procedure go_fishing( p_cursor in out sys_refcursor )

    as

        l_query long := 'select fish_id';

    begin

        for x in (select distinct fish_type from fish order by 1 )

        loop

            l_query := l_query ||
               replace( q'|, sum(decode(fish_type,'$X$',fish_weight)) $X$|',
                        '$X$',
                       dbms_assert.simple_sql_name(x.fish_type) );

       end loop;
   
       l_query := l_query || ' from fish group by fish_id order by fish_id';

   
       open p_cursor for l_query;

   end;

   /
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4smYn.jpg)

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand the question.  Do you want the procedure to `insert` data into a table rather than opening and returning a `sys_refcursor`?  That's possible.  But since you want the results to be dynamic, you'd need the table definition to be dynamic which means that you'd need to create the table in the procedure which would be really, really unusual.  And would mean that only one user could be active at a time which would also be really, really unusual.

Comment: Thank you for caring
I have a table that I want to convert unlimited rows into columns, is there a possible method? I searched a lot and found nothing suitable.
The attached code is the closest thing possible, and I want to display the data in a table or view so that I can display it

Comment: The code you posted returns a `sys_refcursor` which a client application can fetch data from and display the data.  If you just want to display the data, returning a `sys_refcursor` seems much more logical than inserting data into a table.

Comment: @dleendleen Do you need to store the results in a specific table, or is it enough to store it into a new table for each query? If you can create new tables, you can take your existing procedure and replace the `open ...` with something like `execute immediate 'create table table1 as ' || l_query;`

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically pivot the data by using `SYS_REFCURSOR` within a stored function (or procedure)  such as

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Get_Fish_Weight_ByType RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR IS
  v_recordset SYS_REFCURSOR;
  v_sql       VARCHAR2(32767);
  v_cols      VARCHAR2(32767);
BEGIN
  SELECT LISTAGG( ''''||fish_type||''' AS "'||fish_type||'"' , ',' )
                 WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY fish_type )
    INTO v_cols
    FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT fish_type
             FROM fish );

  v_sql :='SELECT * 
             FROM fish e
            PIVOT
            (
             MAX(fish_weight) FOR fish_type IN ( '|| v_cols ||' )
            )';

  OPEN v_recordset FOR v_sql;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_sql);
  RETURN v_recordset;
END;
/
```

which produces and runs the following Select Statement

```
SELECT * 
  FROM fish e
 PIVOT
 (
   MAX(fish_weight) FOR fish_type IN ( 'COD' AS "COD",'CTY' AS "CTY",'HAD' AS "HAD",
                                       'HKE' AS "HKE",'LIN' AS "LIN" )
 )
```

<kbd>[Demo for the produced SQL statement](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=1122d918a4b48b8c380891a8c9b47fdf)</kbd>

and then call the created function from SQL Developer's console as

```
SQL> DECLARE
    res SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
   :res := Get_Fish_Weight_ByType;
END;
/

SQL> PRINT res;
```